# Remove short delay or lag upon clicking button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Is there a way to remove the short delay or lag when i click the button? It seems like nothing is happening then after some seconds only when it loads. This is my code:

```
$('#save-btn').bind('click',function(){

    $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            async: false,
            data : {data:models},
            success: function(result){
                window.location = url2;
            }
        });
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: you can load an animation gif in place of the button until it takes off, but you can't do anything about a slow server, except get a faster one.

Comment: I already done that but it the animation is only showing after the lag

Comment: You don't use `result` in the success-callback, but rather some `url2` variable. So why even wait for the server response? Also, why `async: false,`? Very often it's a bad idea.

Comment: when i set the async to true, my loading indicator loads while it is still not loading. thanks.

Comment: @newbie03 Have you read both parts of my comment?

Comment: yes. i realized that it meant to whatever happens it will redirect to that url2 page.

Comment: Yes, so why wait for the request to return if the redirection does not depend on it?

Comment: you have a point. i modify my code. thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You are waiting until the ajax call returns to redirect to the new url, so those *seconds* are the response time of your server. If it's taking too long to response, it could be that you are returning too much data (ie a full page instead of a json response for example), or you're doing a very complex operation. Odds are it's just the server being slow.

Comment: can i do something about it?

Answer (score 0):

If `save-btn` is an `<input type="submit">` button, use the following code to change its `val()` .

```
$('#save-btn').bind('click',function(){
    $(this).val('loading...');
    $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            async: false,
            data : {data:models},
            success: function(result){
                window.location = url2;
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: the button is not submit. I already put some some loading in that part but it's still the same.